# Unable to change looseness in loops

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have the following code that does not compile if I try to add a looseness flag on the loop on $Z_2$. How to change the looseness of the loop? Note that the code compiles after removing the looseness flag.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows.meta, positioning}

\tikzset{
    ->, % makes the edges directed
    >=stealth, % makes the arrow heads bold
    node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
    every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10}, % sets the properties for each ’state’ node
    initial text=$ $, % sets the text that appears on the start arrow
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[] (z1) at (0,0) {  };
    \node[right = 3cm of z1] (z2) {};
    \draw (z1) edge node[midway,above] {$a$} (z2);
    \draw (z2) edge[loop right,looseness=33] node[above,outer sep=4pt,pos=0.2] {$a$} ();
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

The error message that I get is:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named `' is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.39 \end{frame}
```

Comment: What's your error message? It seems that you will need to specify the target coordinate as well and not leave it out if you change the looseness because setting it resets some settings. Maybe `\tikzset{every loop/.append style={looseness=33}}` for a more general solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve with `\tikzset{->`. It seems that you don't use correctly this command. And your first issue is taht you didn't specify a terminal node for your last edge.

Comment: Try this: `\draw (z2) edge[out=30,in=-30,looseness=30] node[above,outer sep=4pt,pos=0.2] {$a$} (z2);`. You don't need `loop` in this case, if you want to customize the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `looseness = 33` overwrites the `to path` set by the internal `loop` style used by `loop right`.

If we change the definition of the `loop` it seems to work properly.

Alternatively, just specify the start coordinate again as a target.

If you want all loops to have that looseness, adjust the `every loop` style instead:

```
every loop/.append style={looseness=33}
```

Usually, the nodes to be used with loops are bigger and mostly circular which is where the default looseness and/or the min distance seem to be just right.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\tikzset{
  loop/.code={% overwrite default, what will it break?
    \let\tikztotarget\tikztostart,
    \pgfkeysalso{looseness=8,min distance=+5mm,every loop}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth, node distance=3cm]
\node[draw]                    (z1) {};
\node[draw, right = 3cm of z1] (z2) {};
\path (z1) edge node[midway,above] {$a$} (z2)
      (z2) edge[loop right, looseness=33]
                node[above, outer sep=4pt, pos=0.2] {$a$} ()
%           edge[help lines, loop right] () % compare with default
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: That `,` after `\tikztostart` shouldn't be there.